# Setting spring bean property value using ref-bean

Tags: java, spring, velocity

I am trying to set a property value using spring.

```
<bean id="velocityPropsBean" class="com.test.CustomProperties" abstract="false" singleton="true" lazy-init="false" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
    <property name="properties">
   <props>
        <prop key="resource.loader">file</prop>
        <prop key="file.resource.loader.cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="file.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader</prop>
        <prop key="file.resource.loader.path">NEED TO INSERT VALUE AT STARTUP</prop>

    </props>

    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="velocityResourcePath" class="java.lang.String" factory-bean="velocityHelper" factory-method="getLoaderPath"/>
```

Now what i need to do is insert the result from getLoaderPath into file.resource.loader.path. The value of getLoaderPath changes so it has to be loaded at server startup.

Any thoughts how i can inset the velocityResourcePath value to the property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Spring 3, you can skip the middle stage, and invoke the factory directly using [SpringEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef):

```
<prop key="file.resource.loader.path">#{ velocityHelper.loaderPath }</prop>
```

or perhaps

```
<prop key="file.resource.loader.path">#{ velocityHelper.getLoaderPath() }</prop>
```

This would let you remove the `velocityResourcePath` bean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it and get the following error. I am using spring 2.0 - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 17 in XML document from class path resource [velocity-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "prop" must match "null".
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "prop" must match "null".

Answer (score 1):

Below code might help you.

```
<import resource="classpath:/DaoContext.xml"/>

<bean id="ClientMasterDao" class="dao.hibernate.impl.ClientMasterImpl">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ClientMasterServices" class="client.ClientMasterServices">
<property name="clientDao" ref="ClientMasterDao"/>
</bean>
```